# android long running service without notification

Tags: android, service, notifications

I see this example with programs like Advance Task killer, Watch Dog, eBay, battery widgets, ect.  There is a background service running that monitors device activity, a broadcastreceiver, but there is an option to disable the notification icon displayed.  Currently my application works flawlessly by calling:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeBackGroundService.class);
context.startService(intent)
```

and then in my service I am calling:

```
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Now how is it that these other applications can have a long running broadcastreceiver running without a notification icon?  What do I need to do in order to disable/set ect as to hide the icon and add this feature to my application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those apps you mentioned are not guaranteed to keep running. If the system needs to free up memory, it will terminate them if it has to.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not expert on this, but I disagree with the accepted answer.

Your startForeground is key to ensuring that your service continues running.

Without that, it might keep running, but it has a much lower priority so it is much more likely to be killed by the system.

Comment: This is a fact and I have observed it happening. The docs clearly state that your service will be killed if memory needs to be freed up.

Comment: I ended up not going this route at all anyways.  My server was getting nuked and losing my data.  I wrote a class that extends the broadcast receiver and that stores my data do my preference file.  So it is always listening.  I fire of service threads to handle what to do when I get my intended intents.  Which works perfect.

Answer (score -1):

Your service is entirely independent of whether or not a notification exists for it. If you removed the line, startForeground, the service would continue to run. The only time a service stops is if you call context.stopService() or stopSelf(). Throw some logs into your service, and you'll see that it continues to run.

Override the onStartCommand to determine behavior of your service after garbage collection:

```
 @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId() {
      super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
      doWork();
      return START_STICKY;
 }
```

START_STICKY recreates your service after garbage collection. START_REDELIVER_INTENT will recreate your service after garbage collection using the original intent, use this only if you need extra intent data.

Comment: I'll give it a try again, but when I had the code like that in the past either the service or the broadcastreceiver was getting killed.  My application is a long running service to fire off new events or logs when listening to specific device related events.

Comment: Okay I removed startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification); from my service and replaced it with mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification); now after a while of my service running the broadcastreceiver stops receiving.  Any ideas?

Comment: I looked more in to this.  Found out that what is happening is that my broadcastreceiver stops listening.  I think that is is being garbage collected.

Comment: This will happen. In order to define how your service behaves in the event of garbage collection, you have to override onStartCommand and return the desired integer that will either restart the service after garbage collection (START_STICKY) or restart the service with the original intent (START_REDELIVER_INTENT).
I've added the necessary code to the answer.

Comment: Actually I wrote a function to see if my service is running.  Found out that it was.  I did have it starting STICKY, but the issue is that my broadcastreceiver was actually getting collected.  Now that I realize that I am in the process of tackling this from another way

Comment: Good to hear you've made progress. In case you didn't know, BroadcastReceiver are ALWAYS KILLED after the onReceive method finishes. The sole intention of BroadcastReceivers are to check if your app needs to run and to run it if it does, then it dies. So if you have written your code in your BroadcastReceiver expecting it to live longer than onReceive, you need to change that.

Comment: Services will be terminated if startForeground is not used if the system needs to free up memory. That is clearly documented.

Comment: @AndroidDev START_STICKY makes it so that the service is restarted after termination, which is also clearly documented.

Answer (score -3):

Create a notification that contains an icon made with a png and is only 1 pixel in height and width and make that pixel transparent.